# Difference between these two calls: read vs read_iter

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

I am exploring linux kernel code and in vfs_read function, I see these two calls. Can someone explain the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I assume you're referring to this [snippet](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc7/source/fs/read_write.c#L476) of code from `vfs_read()`:

```
if (file->f_op->read)
    return file->f_op->read(file, buf, count, pos);
else if (file->f_op->read_iter)
    return new_sync_read(file, buf, count, pos);
```

Not sure how much background knowledge you have on this, so apologies if I write things you already know. `read` and `read_iter` act as function pointers within a `f_op` (file operations struct). [File operations](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc7/source/include/linux/fs.h#L2022) is a general struct containing a ton of different function pointers/declarations that can be used to manipulate anything considered a file. `read` and `read_iter` are two pointers in that struct.

In reality, we can't know exactly what `read` or `read_iter` are doing unless we know for sure what function is being pointed to for this particular file that is being read. So the more general question is, when do you use the `read` pointer and when should you use the `read_iter` pointer?

The best answer I've seen comes from a [document](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc7/source/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.rst) in the Linux kernel:

```
``read``
called by read(2) and related system calls

``read_iter``
possibly asynchronous read with iov_iter as destination
```

The use of the word "possibly" tells you that these function pointers could in theory be used for whatever, so if you want further details you'd have to look at the specific functions called for a specific file you're interested in.

Comment: So, does it depend on the syscall and the flags?

Comment: It depends on many things, the file type, the syscall, the flags, the device driver. So many things use these two function pointers that it's better to trace through a specific example if you want to see how they work in practice.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This will indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks!

Comment: For more on `iov_iter` see here: https://lwn.net/Articles/625077/